# how to put default user who is creating a session

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add user as a default user who is creating the session,

```
class User(models.Model):

    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Session(models.Model):

    session=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_participitating=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.session
```

Comment: You will not get the current-logged-in user in Django model level. You can fetch the same in any Django view.

Comment: no i am not woking with current logged on,i mean if i am creating a session my name should be there by default

Comment: Do you mean the ForeignKey assign?

Comment: yes,suppose if i took user 'ashu' using foreign key ,he will go by deafult in player_participitating

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin session from django?

Comment: mine is completely diffrent from built in